# Key Management: Hardcode Encryption Key In AFNetworkingReachibilityManager

Tags: ios, encryption, fortify, afnetworking-3

We did review our app for security testing and response we got issue in AFNetworkingReachbilityManager class for Hardcode Encryption Key. Any Idea how to fix this security issue.

Here is the code where they point out hardcode encryption key.

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
   if ([key isEqualToString:@"reachable"] || [key 
      isEqualToString:@"reachableViaWWAN"] || [key 
      isEqualToString:@"reachableViaWiFi"]) {
     return [NSSet setWithObject:@"networkReachabilityStatus"];
  }

     return [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];
  }
```

Comment: There is no encryption key in the code you have shown

Comment: Yes but don't know why they have mentioned this issue and showed as Critical

Comment: Because they are idiots?  Maybe they have used some automatic tool that has triggered on the string "key" and they don't actually know what the code does? Maybe they should highlight some other section of code? Ask them to point out where, specifically, the hard-coded encryption key is.

Comment: @Paulw11 you are right they are not mentioning specific things but just showing automated results. I  think we should mark this question for discussion so that people are aware of these things

Comment: @Paulw11 I am facing the same. can you check my question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302910/key-management-hardcoded-encryption-key-for-chart-js